# .deno_plugins folder created on Deno program API

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

On execution, Deno caches remote imports in a special directory specified by Deno Environment on the first run. The second time and so forth execution of the same piece of the code, i.e, next time you run the program, no downloads are made.
If the program hasn't changed, it won't be retranspiled either.

It is cached in following folders as specified in the documentation

```
On Linux/Redox: **$XDG_CACHE_HOME/deno or $HOME/.cache/deno**
On Windows: **%LOCALAPPDATA%/deno (%LOCALAPPDATA% = FOLDERID_LocalAppData)**
On macOS: **$HOME/Library/Caches/deno**
```

In a project, I am working in, created a `.deno_plugins`

I am using deno_mongo(Native Deno MongoDB driver); is that the reason why this folder is generated? Why and when does .deno_plugins get generated?

[Folder Structure of the project I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0w0J.png)

Note:- PFA the folder structure image.

Comment: deno_plugins upon first execution; this folder is generated, just cached version of the libraries or modules that imported in the codebase. check this blog:https://dev.to/mrshravankumarb/api-with-deno-antidote-for-node-1dka

Answer (score 0):

> **auto-loading prebuilts**

during import the module searches a shared library for your os within the directory `./.deno_plugins` - configurable via environment variable `DENO_PLUGINS`. if the plugin can not be located a suitable prebuilt will be fetched from github releases.

So internaly may be in `deno_mongo` this mechenism is used

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `deno_mongo` has created `.deno_plugins`. The folder is created on the home directory of the file that you run. You must have run the `app.ts` file, so it got created there.